# Reset a network card (not IP stack)

Tags: linux-networking

I have a problem with a network card on a physically inaccessible computer: the network stop working after several hours (no carrier). A software reboot temporarily solve the problem until the next several hours.

`ifdown`/`ifup` don't solve the problem, nor `ip link set down`/`up`, nor anything I tested.

I'd like to try a hardware reset of the network card, as if a reboot was done. How can I achieve that?

I don't want a way to reset the ip stack or whatever software settings.

Comment: What's the bet thus is a Realtek card and you are using the wrong driver?   Not what you want to hear, bit you likely need to ifdown or equivalent so you can rmmod the driver, then modprobe/insmod the driver and ifup etc...

Comment: Even if it's the right driver, I would bet the driver initialization is the right step.

Comment: I'd rather look at root cause of the issue - why NIC gets unresponsible.